# Import data on HDFS to SQL Server or export data on HDFS to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

I had been trying to figure out on which is the best approach for porting data from HDFS to SQL Server.

- Do I import data from Cloudera Hadoop using sqoop Hadoop Connector for SQL Server 2008 R2 or
- Do I export data from Cloudera Hadoop using sqoop into SQL Server

I am sure that both are possible based on the bunch of links I read through

- http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/10/apache-sqoop-overview/
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27584

But when I am looking for possible issues  that could rise at level of configuration and maintenance I don't have proper answers.

I strongly feel that I should go for import, but I am not comfortable in troubleshooting and maintaining the issues that could come up every now and then.

Can someone share their thoughts on what could be the best?

Answer (score 3):

Both of your options use the same method: Apache Sqoop's Export utility. Using the licensed Microsoft connector/driver jar should expectedly yield more performance for the task than using a generic connector offered by Apache Sqoop.

In terms of maintenance, there should be none once you have it working fine. So long as the version of SQL Server in use is supported by the driver jar, it should continue to work as normally expected of it.

In terms of configuration, you may initially have to manually tune to find the best `-m` value for parallelism of your Export MapReduce job launched by the export tool. Using a too high value would cause problems on the DB side, while using a too low value would not give you ideal performance. Some trial and error is required here to arrive at the right `-m` value, along with knowledge of the load periods of your DB, in order to set the parallelism right.

The Apache Sqoop (v1) [doc page](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal) for users of the export tool also lists down a set of common reasons for the failure of the export job. You may want to [view those here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_failed_exports).

On the MapReduce side, you may also want to dedicate a defined scheduler pool or queue for such external-writing jobs as they may be business critical, and schedulers like `FairScheduler` and `CapacityScheduler` help define SLA guarantees on each pool or queue such that the jobs get adequate resources to run when they're launched.